# How do i get specific values from the text file by using socket and through Object Stream in Java?

Tags: java, stream

I have GUI with ComboBox that has three categories `Engineer`, `Manager`, `Administrative Personnel`. When I select one of them it should display information about e.g. `Engineer` I am using text file with details. I want to retrieve specific values from the text file e.g. when `Engineer` is selected the request should go to the server through socket and then server response back with selected specific information using `Object Stream`.
The problem I have with this code is that it's only giving me first line from the text file by using `Object Stream` in and out. I want the server to look for that three engineer names and response back with three to display on `JTextArea`. `

```
try {
    out = new ObjectOutputStream (socket.getOutputStream ());
    C3TextArea.setText ("");
    out.writeObject (C3TextArea.getText ());

    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream (socket.getInputStream ());
    String r = (String) in.readObject ();
    System.out.println ("Server Recived" + in .readObject ());
    C3TextArea.setText ((String) r);

} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger (ViewFrame.class.getName ()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) { }

public class Server {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            ServerSocket Listener = new ServerSocket (7000);

            while (true) {

                Socket client = Listener.accept ();

                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream (client.getInputStream ());
                String r = (String) in.readObject ();
                System.out.println ("Ser Recived" + r);

                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream (client.getOutputStream ());
                File file = new File ("employee.txt");
                Scanner scan = new Scanner (file);
                while (scan.hasNext ()) {
                    out.writeObject (scan.nextLine ());
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger (Server.class.getName ()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

My text file:

```
Engineer, John Eng1,12345, 1000.00,10
Manager, Jim Man1,23451, 1500.00, 500.00
Manager, Jim Man2,34512, 2000.00, 100.00
AdministrativePersonnel, Helen Adm1,45123, 20.0, 40.0
Engineer, Maria Eng2,51234, 1200.00,12
Manager, Jim Man3,23456, 1200.00,600.00
AdministrativePersonnel, John Doe1,34562, 15.0, 30.0
Engineer, Mary Eng3,45612, 2000.00,20
AdministrativePersonnel, Nick Doe2,56234, 22.0, 45.0
Manager, Ann Man4,62345, 2300.00, 400.00
```

`

Comment: Well, your client only calls readObject() once. Why would it get more than one object? And seriously, if you want to understand what your code does, indent it. Your IDE can do that for you.

Comment: This is in my assignment and it mentioned there that i have to use Object Stream.

Comment: OK. But does it forbid you from calling readObject() more than once, and from indenting your code?

Comment: I am a beginer is there any way to send multiple lines from server to client and display it on Jtextarea

Comment: It does call but only one line and I need specific multiple lines

Comment: It seems you're not reading my comments. Your server calls writebject() in a loop. Once for each line. Your client only calls readObject() once. So it only reads one object.